# php mysql problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have installed php and mysql on windows xp with iis 5.1 as my web server. But when i run the following code it just shows me a blank page. Can anybody let me know where i am wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: If it ran successfully, what would you expect to see?

Comment: Is PHP working at all? Is  error reporting turned on (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`)

Comment: Did you try to see a page source?

Comment: Since he doesn't output anything on success, looking at the page source wouldn't change a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it doesn't generate any output if the connection succeeds so that's probably what's happening. What would you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'xxxx') or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

what does this print ?
* make sure you have mysql running
* make sure you have php running on IIS
* try to check in php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
  die('Connection ok!');
}
```